# Map object fields with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to map a part of my object, but I'm having some undefined variables. Here is my object (data, which is array of objects) dumped into json :

```
[
  {
    "key": "Sam",
    "values": [
      {
        "label": "Name",
        "value": 38
      },
      {
        "label": "Surname",
        "value": 38
      },
      {
        "label": "Phone",
        "value": 36
      },
      {
        "label": "Text",
        "value": 38
      },
      {
        "label": "Website",
        "value": 28
      },
      {
        "label": "Rating",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "label": "Factor",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "Cases",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "Hours",
        "value": 5
      }
    ],
    "color": "#E05353"
  },
  {
    "key": "Niki",
    "values": [
      {
        "label": "Name",
        "value": 38
      },
      {
        "label": "Surname",
        "value": 38
      },
      {
        "label": "Phone",
        "value": 37
      },
      {
        "label": "Text",
        "value": 38
      },
      {
        "label": "Website",
        "value": 4
      },
      {
        "label": "Rating",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "label": "Factor",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "Cases",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "label": "Hours",
        "value": 0
      }
    ],
    "color": "#293F90"
  },
  {
    "key": "Dan",
    "values": [
      {
        "label": "Name",
        "value": 21
      },
      {
        "label": "Surname",
        "value": 21
      },
      {
        "label": "Phone",
        "value": 6
      },
      {
        "label": "Text",
        "value": 21
      },
      {
        "label": "Website",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "Rating",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "Factor",
        "value": 3
      },
      {
        "label": "Cases",
        "value": 5
      },
      {
        "label": "Hours",
        "value": 1
      }
    ],
    "color": "#32B6E8"
  },
  {
    "key": "Jake",
    "values": [
      {
        "label": "Name",
        "value": 58
      },
      {
        "label": "Surname",
        "value": 58
      },
      {
        "label": "Phone",
        "value": 56
      },
      {
        "label": "Text",
        "value": 58
      },
      {
        "label": "Website",
        "value": 30
      },
      {
        "label": "Rating",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "Factor",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "Cases",
        "value": 1
      },
      {
        "label": "Hours",
        "value": 2
      }
    ],
    "color": "#77B242"
  },
  {
    "key": "Steve",
    "values": [
      {
        "label": "Name",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "label": "Surname",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "label": "Phone",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "label": "Text",
        "value": 100
      },
      {
        "label": "Website",
        "value": 33
      },
      {
        "label": "Rating",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "Factor",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "label": "Cases",
        "value": 0
      },
      {
        "label": "Hours",
        "value": 17
      }
    ],
    "color": "#FFA614"
  }
]
```

What I need to do is to multiply value by 100 for each key its values. Here is what I got :

```
$.each(data, function(i,val){
      $.each(val.values, function(i,v){
        v.value = (v.value * 100);
      });
    });
```

Senior developer told me I could do this better with `$.map`, how?

Comment: I really don't see any advantage using `$.map` here. `$.each` is perfectly fine. You can shorten it a tine bit by using `v.value *= 100;`. *edit:* That's under the assumption that you want to keep that structure.

Comment: did you check what `val` actually is? what do you see when you `console.log` it?

Comment: `arr = $.map(arr, function(v, i){
 return v.value = (v.value * 100);
});` when using the mapper.. But the undefines are not from using foreach.

Comment: @Sven: What is `arr` here? If you return just the number, then you map the objects to numbers. You have to return the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the map version - though I disagree with your "senior" developer that it's better:

```
var mappedObjects = $.map(data, function(val){
      return { 
          key: val.key, 
          values: $.map(val.values, function(v) { return { label: v.label, value: v.value * 100 }; }
      };
});
```

In my opinion the code you have is a lot clearer, not to mention the fact that, as Felix mentioned below, you're needlessly creating a lot of new objects.

Comment: It's certainly a waste of memory (creating all these objects) :-/

Comment: Ahh - that's a good point - I just figured the code was a lot clearer how OP already had it - I didn't even consider that aspect.